# Python typing how to describe the type of

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I'd like to define a signature for "factory function" that has one parameter as type descriptor and returning value is the instance fitting to this type.

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVariable("T")
my_list = typing.List[str]

def a_factory(descriptor:???) -> T:
  pass

var = a_factory(my_list) #iferred type should be `my_list`, i.e. List[str]
```

This works for plain types by using `typing.Type[T]` and IDE properly recorgnizes variable type with the following signature

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVariable("T")

def a_factory(descriptor:typing.Type[T]) -> T:
  pass

var = a_factory(str) #type is inferred as str properly
```

, but so far I can't find the proper construct in `???` for type descriptors

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you expect here. `def foo(d: Type[T]) -> T` makes sense, it takes a type and returns an instance of that type. But `List[str]` is not a type, it's an instance of `list` which contains instances of `str`.

Comment: I know, I'm working on some declarative "dsl like" component that would allow to describe something similar to json schemas. The whole idea here is to provide users to work with described structure in a "type-safe" way.
E.g. by 
`class A:  myField = a_factory("list of strings", typing.List[str])`

Comment: I know I can specify type for field, but a_factory also uses this info under the hood for some dynamic goodies, so it leads to duplicating it twice